# The same MySQL query shows up multiple times on Hibernate console probably causing the slow response

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, hibernate, jdbc

I recently encountered by activating `setShowSql(true)` shows me many MySQL queries repeatedly several times(mostly 3 times) while testing on development mode where I have just one user session.And that is the main cause of my website slowdown during high traffic and by monitoring my website on new relic monitoring system, it shows me always `DataSource.getConnection()` holding so much time. please checkout this following screenshot..

[image]

I still not sure what is the main cause behind of this slowness.and Few developers suggested me to use `@PostConstruct` is the contract that guarantees that this method will be invoked only once in the bean lifecycle.but it doesnt work at all.

For instance here mysql query which repeats several times.

```
Hibernate: select count(favorite0_.id) as col_0_0_ from favorite favorite0_ left outer join User user1_ on favorite0_.user_id=user1_.id where user1_.id is null

Hibernate: select count(favorite0_.id) as col_0_0_ from favorite favorite0_ left outer join User user1_ on favorite0_.user_id=user1_.id where user1_.id is null

Hibernate: select count(favorite0_.id) as col_0_0_ from favorite favorite0_ left outer join User user1_ on favorite0_.user_id=user1_.id where user1_.id is null
```

Here is my connection pool configuration (Tomcat 7´s context.xml)

```xml
<Resource auth="Container"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          maxActive="100"
          maxIdle="10"
          name="jdbc/fappi"
          password="xxxxxxxx"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coexi useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"
          username="root"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="600000"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="100"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          testOnBorrow="true" />
```

I request to all of you to please give me suggestions.

Many thanks in advance..
Tim

Comment: @Tiny, Thanks for making it proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a [N+1 query issue to me](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/).

You should use [an automatic SQL statement validator](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils) to ensure that the number of SQL statements generated by a data access layer method is the expected one.

Comment: Thanks alot for giving me your suggestion. Anyway, I just want to know if I have been maintaining many different logs in my project, Does it also cause to my website slowness??

Comment: Too much logging can affect application performance indeed. That's why an [async logger is a better choice](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html).

Comment: Is my connection pooling configuration ok to handle big traffic especially, when we have 5 different high speed CPU to handle? And I am created spin up for MYSQL server.(which means using sperate part for mysql server) I dont know if it is good idea or not? please give me some suggestions.